# Comparing two large data sets or tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, list, csv, dataset

Lets say I have 2 large csv files (more than 1 million rows) and both are a list of names with rank. The goal is to find the same names among both lists, unique names to list 1, and unique names to list 2.

I wanted to do this is mySQL so I created a table for each list but looping through over a million records a million times seems like a poor way of doing this and very slow. How would you do this?

This is an example but bad query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f272/2

Comment: So you want three results: 1.same/similar names 2.)unique in 1 3.) unique in 2? What means similar?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the same not similar.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns the number of times that names appear in each table, with the count.  If names are unique in each table, then it might return something like:

```
InTable1   InTable2    Count
1          0           xxx
0          1           yyy
1          1           zzz
```

The query uses a `union all` and `group by`:

```
select InTable1, InTable2, count(*), min(name), max(name)
from (select name, sum(which = 1) as InTable1, sum(which = 2) as InTable2
      from ((select name, 1 as which
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select name, 2 as which
             from table2
            )
           ) t
      group by name
     ) t
group by InTable1, InTable2;
```

EDIT:

You need to create indexes.  Here is the syntax:

```
create index table1_name on table1(name);
create index table2_name on table2(name);
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a count, names only appear once in each list but they are sometimes in one list and not the other.

Comment: @DaveLobby . . . The query will do that.  When I face this problem, I look at the counts.  It helps make sure that assumptions about the data are correct.

Comment: Your suggestion: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f272/1 and this is what I want but with a better query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f272/2

Comment: @DaveLobby . . . Your query is fine.  Just add an index on `table2(name)`.